# Error with setcap CAP_SYS_TIME+ep /user/mybinaryprogram

Tags: linux, capabilities

I'm trying to use the capabilities (CAP_SYS_TIME) but when I run this command:

setcap CAP_SYS_TIME+ep /user/mybinaryprogram

on my system, I get the following error:

```
Failed to set capabilities on file '/bin/date' (Invalid argument)
usage: setcap [-q] [-v] (-r|-|<caps>) <filename> [ ... (-r|-|<capsN>) 
<filenameN> ]
Note <filename> must be a regular (non-symlink) file.
```

My system: Linux t2080rdb 4.1.35-rt41 ppc64 GNU/Linux
 I have obtained the linux image with Yocto Project SDK 2.0
 Effectively when doing 'ls -la' in the bin directory, date appears as a 
 symlink

According to the tests I have been doing I always get the same error when trying to do a setcap.

I solved the problem, the command did not work because the kernel did not have the 'Security Labels' enabled

Comment: please copy-paste the **exact** command you were using; the one from your question will cause a different error message. If you have the right permissions, you can set that cap with `setcap CAP_SYS_TIME+ep /path/to/file`. But setting that capability on `/bin/date` (or the real executable that's a symlink to) is a **horrible** idea; why do you want to do that?

Comment: The exact command that I am trying to make is:
set_cap CAP_SYS_TIME+ep  /bin/date
And the error is the one described in the question.

What I want to do is that a restricted privilege user can use an application that uses the linux functions gettimeofday() and settimeofday(). Any suggestions on how to do it?

Comment: [I assume that `set_cap` is  `setcap` and not something else I don't know about] You cannot set that capability on a symlink, but on the real executable it points to; and letting everyone mess with the system time is a bad idea, so you should restrict who can run it. Example (untested): `cp /bin/date /p/t/date; chgrp setdate /p/t/date; chmod 750 /p/t/date; setcap CAP_SYS_TIME+ep /p/t/date`. But I really don't see the point of it; the time should **not** be user-modifiable; it should be set via ntp or some gps device or, as a last resort, asked when booting up.

Comment: Notice that no privileges are needed to use gettimeofday(); everyone can use it.

Comment: Yes, set_cap is setcap. The problem is that when I try to enable CAP_SYS_TIME on any regular file I always get the same error. I think it is a problem of the command or that in my system it is necessary to enable something to get enable capabilities.

Comment: The filesystem should support extended attributes. Not all do (notably, tmpfs on many devices does not)

Comment: I haven't used yocto project but the fact that /bin/date is a symlink suggests that it's using busybox, where **all** the programs are actually links to a single binary. This means that all "programs" share their capabilities ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command did not work because the kernel did not have the 'Security Labels' enabled. 
To install these modules in the kernel I have performed the command

```
$ bitbake -c menuconfig virtual / kernel
```

and I have navigated through the menu to enable

- Ext2 extended attributes and * Ext2 Security Labels